# Installing skaffold with choco get error?

Tags: chocolatey, skaffold

I am new `chocolatey` and `skaffold`. Installing choco `windows` was successfully but when I run this command: `choco install -y skaffold` get this error:

```
Installing the following packages:
skaffold
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
skaffold not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Unable to obtain lock file access on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\c56b0f2c2ba3451f507c4c2852dd4c8f9d406865' for operations on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\skaffold'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\c56b0f2c2ba3451f507c4c2852dd4c8f9d406865' will allow NuGet to continue.
skaffold package files install failed with exit code 1. Performing other installation steps.
This is try 1/3. Retrying after 300 milliseconds.
 Error converted to warning:
 Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey".
This is try 2/3. Retrying after 400 milliseconds.
 Error converted to warning:
 Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey".
Maximum tries of 3 reached. Throwing error.
Cannot create directory "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey". Error was:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey".
   в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   в System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   в System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   в chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.<>c__DisplayClass63_0.<CreateDirectory>b__1()
   в chocolatey.infrastructure.tolerance.FaultTolerance.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Retry>b__0()
   в chocolatey.infrastructure.tolerance.FaultTolerance.Retry[T](Int32 numberOfTries, Func`1 function, Int32 waitDurationMilliseconds, Int32 increaseRetryByMilliseconds, Boolean isSilent)
   в chocolatey.infrastructure.tolerance.FaultTolerance.Retry(Int32 numberOfTries, Action action, Int32 waitDurationMilliseconds, Int32 increaseRetryByMilliseconds, Boolean isSilent)
   в chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.CreateDirectory(String directoryPath, Boolean isSilent)
   в chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.EnsureDirectoryExists(String directoryPath, Boolean ignoreError, Boolean isSilent)

Chocolatey installed 0/0 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey".
```

I dont understand what is mean. How to fix it?

Comment: It is a problem of lacking access privileges.

Comment: Is possible solve this? I run every command on powershell admin

Comment: If you're not on Chocolatey 2.2.2, can I suggest upgrading to that and retrying?

Comment: I did this but not help

Comment: And I add into PATH C:\ProgramData\cholocatey\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open an Administrator Command Prompt (right click Command Prompt and select "Run as Administrator"), then run command